# Project Type in VS2015 Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-shell

I have created a working Shell with VS2015 ..it is working fine but Now i have created project types using **visual studio 2015 common project system** library. it shows new project dialog (with new project types in project templates) and wizard and almost all processing but before creation file structure it is getting fails and i am getting following error

[Error : project type does not support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIQ4t.png)

Note :
1.It works fine on machines has VS2015. 
2.Project system assembly is inside shell's bin\Extension\Application

Comment: Does it a visual studio isolated shell. does it not work without installing visual studio 2015 and work with installing vs2015?

Comment: @Cole Wu - Apart from project type it works fine even without VS2015 but project type works fine on machine has VS2015...it strange because SQL Management studio has project types and they work even without VS20xx.